# Spring Config uri

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-config

I have configured bootstrap.yml for spring config

```
spring:
  application:
    name: cce-auth
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://temp.com:8888
```

It works fine but I need URI value Dynamically, for example if I will publish this `.war` in test environment this URL must be `http://test-temp.com:8888`.

So for this I have solution create config.txt file in server and using I/O Stream reed/write  this string to bootstrap.yml.

But problem is loading, spring loads `http://localhost:8888` before I'm writing in bootstrap.yml.

So my reason is to create dynamically URI for config server. 
DO you have any idea?

Comment: use a substitution and let boot do it `uri: {$config.server.url}`. And set that as a system property or environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Define active_profile in `bootstrap.yml` file

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${activatedProperties}
```

Then create `bootstrap-${activatedProperties}.yml` for each environment, etc..`bootstrap-dev.yml`, `bootstrap-pre.yml`, `bootstrap-prod.yml`

For example:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: servicename_prod
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: https://admin:123456@test.com:8888
server:
  port: 8443
```

add plugin to `pom.xml` file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When run java, define environment on it: for example, run with `prod` environment.

```
java -Dserver.port=8443 -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar ....
```